# How to show SMSs from a specific contact

Tags: android

From the SMS content provider I was able to extract a list of contacts with whom I have messaged (as in the native messaging app). Right now, if I select one of the contacts, all the SMS inbox and outbox is shown. How can I show only the messages from the selected contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
String[] smsNo={"YOUR_NUMBER"};
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
                   Uri.parse("content://sms"), null,"address=?", smsNo, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  
                int index_Body = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");  
                do {   
                    String strbody = cursor.getString(index_Body);  
                } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
            }
```

Comment: the query works, thank you very much :) However, in your code I need to hardcode the contact number, is there a way to extract it dynamically based on the selected row from the list in the previous page?

Comment: `query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)` it take an selection Args as an array of string so you make a logic and just pass a selected phone number in array from prev page

Comment: can you explain this in detail please? I'm just getting started with Android development :D